# ruled surface over $\Bbb{P}^1$ contains the affine plane $\Bbb{A}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I was reading Algebraic Geometry over the Complex Numbers written by Arapura. In chapter 11, page 191.

Define the ruled surface to be a $\Bbb{P}^1$ bundle over $C$ for some complex algebraic curve $C$, such that locally it isomorphic to $U_i\times \Bbb{P}^1$ for Zariski open cover $\{U_i\}$ of the curve $C$.

I want to prove that they are birational equivalent to $\Bbb{P}^2$, the book says since the ruled surface and $\Bbb{P}^2$ both contain $\Bbb{A}^2$, therefore we can get the results.

It's not very obvious to me why the ruled surface contains $\Bbb{A}^2$, I will try to see what happens if $C = \Bbb{P}^1$, then the ruled surface is simply $\Bbb{P}^1 \times \Bbb{P}^1$, then it contains $\Bbb{A}^1 \times \Bbb{A}^1$ but it seems not to be $\Bbb{A}^2$?

Comment: There are a lot of errors in this post. I'd suggest going back and rereading your text (plus adding the source to your question).

Comment: A ruled surface over projective line is not necessary isomorphic to a product of two projective lines, but it can be any Hirzebruch surface.

Comment: Thank you @danneks , I know it needs not to isomorphic to product of two projective line, what I did is try to prove it for this special case.

Comment: @Hank Scorpio , I am not sure , is it ok now?

Comment: No. The claim that a ruled surface is birational to $\Bbb P^2$ means that $C$ has to be $\Bbb P^1$, so that's a pretty big issue; the claim that $\Bbb A^1\times\Bbb A^1\not\cong\Bbb A^2$ is mystifying to me, why do you think that? It seems like you just kind of post here without trying to do too much thinking on your own. Yes, learning advanced math is hard, but I feel like you have to be able to put a little more effort in on your own - struggling with a problem for a little bit is valuable and builds your ability to figure things out.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the valuable advice. Hank Scorpio.

Comment: @Hank Scorpio , $\Bbb A^1\times\Bbb A^1\not\cong\Bbb A^2
$ since they have different topology? as Zariski topology on $\Bbb{A}^2$ is not the same as on the product space, and can you provide a bit hint that why $C\times \Bbb{P}^1$ birational to $\Bbb{P}^2$ means $C$ has to be $\Bbb{P}^1$

Comment: @HankScorpio I find that very condescending. It is okay to have misconceptions, and it is okay to ask a question with a lot of mistakes.

Comment: Thank you @Nico, but maybe you misunderstood what Hank Scorpio means, what he wants to stress is that work out the question on my own will be a better choice to get the ability to figure things out. that is more important than this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product topology (of Zariski topolgies) on $\mathbb{A}^1\times \mathbb{A}^1$ is not the same as the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^2$, but topological product of Zariski topology is not what is usually meant by $\mathbb{A}^1 \times \mathbb{A}^1$, $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ or $U_i \times \mathbb{P}^1$ in the definition of a $\mathbb{P}^1$ bundle. In Arapura, look at Proposition 2.4.6 for the definition of product of (pre)varieties.

The analytic topology on $\mathbb{A}^2$ is on the other hand the same as the product of the analytic topologies on $\mathbb{A}^1$ and $\mathbb{A}^2$ (and more generally for $X \times Y$).

Comment: Do you mean "not the same as the Zariski topology on $\Bbb{A}^2$" ?

Comment: Here in the book it means to be analytic topology or Zariski topology?

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo. I've added a line about analytic topology. I'm not familiar with the book's convention, but it looks like sections 2.3 and 2.4 do not use analytic/classical topology, which is consistent with a remark along those lines at the beginning of 2.3. Section 2.5 seems to be explicit in statements that need the classical topology.